# EBDB contact manager: where do I can find a guide to use it?

Tags: org-mode

I would start to manage my contact with emacs. I've found that contact-manager and EBDB are the best way ro handle it. But I do not find anywhere a place that drive me to :
1 - build a DB
2 - use it

in the EBDB manual (https://github.com/girzel/ebdb/blob/master/ebdb.org#ebdb-manual) I was not able to understand how to use it inside emacs and how to create a DB

Can someone show me a complete guide to use it?

Thank you

Renato

Comment: Best way, you mean they look better than `org-contacts` (which I prefer, for simple/small contact databases)? But then, which part of the manual you did not understand? I tried creating a database using [these instructions](https://github.com/girzel/ebdb/blob/master/ebdb.org#starting-a-new-database), and it worked fine. Creating a contact/record using [these instructions](https://github.com/girzel/ebdb/blob/master/ebdb.org#creating-records), worked fine also. Subsequently, saving worked fine also (by pressing `s`, as explained just above the 'Creating Records' section?

Comment: Or do you mean you did not understand how to install it?